# Can Shared Packed Parse Forest have more than 2 families?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, parsers

I am implementing Earley parser and using algorithm from [Elizabeth Scott's paper "SPPF-Style Parsing From Earley Recognisers"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1571066108001497) (section 4).

Author says

> A family of children of u will consist
> of one or two nodes.

However algorithm as described in paper fails at following grammar:

```
<S> ::= <A> | <B> | <C>
<A> ::= 'a'
<B> ::= 'a'
<C> ::= 'a'
```

because it attempts to create more than 2 families of children.

I don't understand what I'm missing.
Do I just keep unrestricted amount of families (amount of family children still is capped at 2) and time/space complexity will still remain cubic, or I need introduce additional non-terminals to grammar so there are no more than 2 rules per non-terminal?